# GA Unable to add users

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to add users to Google Analytics, but i am getting error like,

**This user did not satisfy this organization's user policy.**

What is the main cause of this issue? Can anyone from the GA background please help me to escape from this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when ehe email added is some kind of alias and it isn't on the same email server, so in this case you can try to add the email of the account behind it and it should work.

Comment: Appreciate your help, can you please explain the solution in detail please? From my end what i need to do or what should i share to user.

Comment: You should ask what the actual email is because the one they gave you is not recognized. Furthermore, the email must be a Google account (or a gmail or company email registered as Google account)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time and effort.